# Python -- sympy solve() returning another equation instead of value

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

This creates a list of points and the sympy `solve()` method should be returning the value of x.  Instead it's returning yet another equation, and I'm not sure why.  The `ogrid()` and `ravel()` are creating a list of points in the plot and this is on Matplotlib, if that makes a difference but I don't think it should.  It should be finding root(s) of the equation.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here that causes it to not return a value, but instead returns another equation:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib import rc
import random
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import *

a = -2; b = 1
y, x = np.ogrid[-10:10:100j, -10:10:100j]
xlist = x.ravel(); ylist = y.ravel()
elliptic_curve = pow(y, 2) - pow(x, 3) - x * a - b
plt.contour(xlist, ylist, elliptic_curve, [0])
randmid = random.randint(30,70)
#y = ylist[randmid]; x = xlist[randmid]
xsym, ysym = symbols('x ylist[randmid]')
x_result = solve(pow(ysym, 2) - pow(xsym, 3) - xsym * a - b, xsym) # 11/5/13 needs to return a value
```

I'm teaching myself Python so this is probably something a junior programmer can help me out with, but if a pro sees this and can spare a moment to help that'd be great.

EDIT:

Returns a value for y roughly 3.xx where there's not 3 possible x-values:

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `lambdify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x_result` is a list of expressions, which is the solutions of your equation. It's not a list of value because `ysym` is a symbol. If you want the numeric results, you need call `subs()` and `evalf()`:

```
[e.subs({ysym:ylist[randmid]}).evalf() for e in x_result]
```

output:

```
[0.0871073310916539 - 8.0e-17*I,
 1.36864647418387 + 4.37e-17*I,
 -1.45575380527552 + 3.63e-17*I]
```

Comment: I'll definitely remember that in the future, +1.  But I added an edit to show why it's not not working.  At y=3 (roughly), not only are there not 3 x-values but none of the ones listed seems to get even close to the plot.